# ssh vs file associations / mime types

Tags: ssh, syntax-highlighting, mime-types, gedit

So, on my local machine I tweaked my
/usr/(local/)share/mime/packages/freedesktop.org.xml,
to make a few additional file extensions be detected as PHP.

```
<glob pattern="*.inc"/>
<glob pattern="*.module"/>
<glob pattern="*.install"/>
```

(this is for Drupal files)

nautilus uses this information to open the file in gedit.
gedit uses this information to enable the correct PHP syntax colors.

---

Now, I want the same for files opened via ssh.
I know this used to work in the past, but I don't remember what exactly I changed.
Whatever I did back then, it was probably wiped with the 11.10 Oneiric Ocelot upgrade.

What I want,

- open an ssh folder in nautilus
- double-click a file named "something.module"
- have it open in gedit, with the correct PHP syntax colors enabled.

Comment: The solution was to run

    sudo update-mime-database /usr/share/mime

after doing the changes.  
Funnily, for local files this was not necessary, but for remote (ssh) files, it was.

I hope this does help someone.  
I already know I will come back here, next time I have to repair my configuration after a dist upgrade.

(I'm going to post this as a solution, if I still remember it after the 15 hours)

Comment: and now it's not working again.. update-mime-database does not work.

Answer (score 0):

There are different things you might want to check.

1) Edit `/usr/(local/)share/mime/packages/freedesktop.org.xml`
Search for "php", and the section with `<glob>`. Add your own extensions there, as explained in the question above.

2) Run `sudo update-mime-database /usr/share/mime`
You might have to do this after you changed the settings as in (1).

3) Edit `/usr/share/gtksourceview-3.0/language-specs/php.lang` (path may vary)
Look for `<property name="globs">`, and add your custom extensions.
(see http://live.gnome.org/Gedit/FAQ#How_to_set_the_default_highlight_mode_for_new_files.3F)

4) Restart gedit.
Probably enough to just close and re-open the tab where you wanted to edit, but if that doesn't help, close and re-open all gedit windows.